# Boot Windows 10 from SSD (solid state drive)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I cloned my system with mini partition wizard 10 to my new SSD. The SSD is MBR. BIOS is set to boot from USB first. When I go to boot I get a "select your keyboard" blue screen followed by a windows repair screen with troubleshooting options. Please help me figure out what to do so that I can get windows 10 to boot from my SSD so I can switch over completely to running on SSD.

[image: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7xyBD0Aj42xRkhoR3pPTFlUb3c]

I noticed the sizes don't match up exactly.

Comment: Most SSDs require you use UEFI thus in the case of Windows. the GPT schema

Comment: If you are going to provide a screenshot with multiple disks, you need to at least explain, what we are looking at

Comment: Why did you change your partition scheme from gpt to mbr? That is the first problem. Your BIOS is set to boot UEFI, that is the only way your original drive is working.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it being an SSD doesn't matter in this case. SSDs are identical in general capability to HDDs, at least from the OS/users perspective. The differences are primarily in seek speed, resistance to kinetic shock, and the fact that SSDs tend to support trim (to counteract a potentially destructive difference in the way the two storage technologies work). As a rule, treat any SSD as if it were an HDD.

The problem, as others pointed out, is that you somehow managed to change the GTP style partition scheme to an MBR one. The main problem with this is that UEFI requires a GPT partition scheme... and the Windows installation you just cloned expects a UEFI boot process. By changing the partition scheme to MBR during the clone process you've made UEFI unusable and "corrupted" that boot process.

Your best option is to clone the drive again, but this time keep GPT as the partition scheme.